# Why does the head pointer lose track of the linkedlist when overwriting the current head node

Tags: data-structures, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Comparing:

```
public static ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2)
    {
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode head = dummy;

        while (list1 != null && list2 != null)
        {
            if (list1.val < list2.val)
            {
                dummy.next = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
            }
            else
            {
                dummy.next = list2;
                list2 = list2.next;
            }

            dummy = dummy.next;
        }
        if (list1 == null)
        {
            dummy.next = list2;
        }
        else if (list2 == null)
        {
            dummy.next = list1;
        }
        return head.next;
    }
```

To:

```
 public static ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2)
        {
            ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
            ListNode head = dummy;

        while (list1 != null && list2 != null)
        {
            if (list1.val < list2.val)
            {
                dummy = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
            }
            else
            {
                dummy = list2;
                list2 = list2.next;
            }

            dummy = dummy.next;
        }
        if (list1 == null)
        {
            dummy.next = list2;
        }
        else if (list2 == null)
        {
            dummy.next = list1;
        }
        return head.next;
    }
```

What is the difference in respect to how head points to the dummy ListNode.

My understanding was instead of using dummy.next = list1 and just having dummy = list1, we would essentially be rewriting the current value of dummy. Then when we get to:

```
dummy = dummy.next;
```

Dummy will equal null. So when we get to the next iteration of the loop we will resassign null to the whatever node is in list1. So why is head not able to keep track of dummy when we do this? Is it because we are assigning the first node of dummy to a different list?

Comment: It is not clear which changes you are discussing. If you replace the assignment to dummy with `dummy = list1`, then there is no -1 node. Please provide the alternative code for this function as a whole, so we understand what you are referring to.

Comment: Please edit the question. Just put the function's code there with your alternative. Then there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yes, I hope the answer clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only mutate a list by assigning values to *properties* of nodes, not by assigning values to local variables.

Just like `list1 = list1.next` does not *alter* `list1`, but merely moves a reference to the next node in that list, so `dummy = list1` does not alter that list either. It merely sets a reference to a node; nothing alters in that list.

So in your second version, `dummy` starts as reference to a node with value -1, but then in the first iteration of the loop *abandons* that node, and refers to another node in `list1`. So the node with value -1 *never* gets anything assigned to its `next` member, which remains `null` until the very end of the function's execution.